# content query webpart in sharepoint 2013 fetches only Title

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

```
The content query webpart in sharepoint 2013 fetches only Title. I am pointing to a Content type using it. Even though it contains many columns still Content Query displays only Title. 
How can I customize it to point to some columns in that content type?
```

Also is there any other alternative to get data of columns of a particular content type?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to modify the itemstyle.xsl in the style library, and add a new template that can pull through the columns of your items.